# cocos2d-x 3: cross-platform data handling

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using cocos2d-x 3.2alpha0 and want to save some game stuff. It should work for android/ios/win32.

The wiki says: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_read_and_write_file_on_different_platforms
(it's from 2011)

Forum says this: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/please-help-cocos2d-x-to-determine-whats-the-correct-path-to-save-a-file-on-ios-and-android/5578 (it's from 2013)

I am not sure if ileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath(); really works for all platforms.

Any advice on this?

Comment: have you read the thread? Plenty of advice there, so what exactly do you need to know or are unsure of?

Comment: Plenty of advice? The only stuff I read is "it should be there, not there because it will be purged from the system" or "the documentation says there but apple rejected the app because it was there". When I am using a framework for cross platform development I want the framework to give me a path which works. What I want to know? Is getWritablePath() secure for saving permanent files?

Comment: no, not for permanent files, that's what the thread is saying with all the bits about cache and os clearing cache folders etc. For permanent files you have to save them to the "app data" or "user documents" folder. There ought to be a method for that too. Check the api reference.